# using foreach mysqli query with ajax form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am fairly new to jquery and ajax and I'm trying to incorporate into all my forms. I can do the more simple forms, but this one has got me stumped. The facts are:

1.at least 1 input field must be filled

2.all input filed's are checked via mysqli_query

3.when an input field has a value which is not found in mysql, the foreach loop breaks and that value variable is echoed, followed by " is not a member".

the problem is I can echo "success" or "fail" and then use that in the ajax 'success function(response)' to do somethin with it but how can I take the variable value and incorporate that into an alert like: alert(//$value// is not a member)? here is the php:

```
foreach($_POST as $value)
{
    $usercheck =  "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$value'";
    $usercheck = $db->query($usercheck);

    if($usercheck->num_rows !== 0 || $value =="") 
    {
        $x="1";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $x="2";
    }
    break;
}

if($value == "") 
{
    echo "none filled in";
} 
else
    if ($x == "1")
    {
        echo "all filled boxes are users";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo $value." is not a user";
    }
```

Comment: what message gets sent if server validation passes? Also show your jQuery ajax code

Comment: right now, nothing eventually it would be a header to another page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be best to send back a message when validation passes like `"ok"`. Then in ajax success you can check if the message is `"ok"` and if it is you can redirect where you want. If it isn't valid, do somethig with the returned message.

```
$.ajax({
   url:'/path/to server'/,
   success:function(response){
      if(response=='ok'){
         /* do redirect*/
         window.location='someOtherpage';
      }else{
         $('#formErrorElementID').text( response);
     }
  }
});
```

If you need to send back a specific url for user to go to can modify response to use JSON and send back something like:

```
{ "status": "ok", "url": "newPage.php"}
```

OR

```
{ "status": "fail", "message": "is not a user"}
```

Then in AJAX `success`

```
    if(response.status=='ok'){
         /* do redirect*/
         window.location=response.url;
      }else{
         $('#formErrorElementID').text( response.message);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Firstly, I would like to mention a significant security gap in your SQL procedure. Whenever you run a query, you always want to sanitize your entries so as to prevent injection attacks. Some ways of doing this is through [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). This way, the potentially malicious user input won't be executed:

```
$usercheck = $db->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$usercheck->execute(array($value));
```

As mentioned above, I think a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) object would be a most practical, as it is an object structure compatible with many languages. Your last three 'echos', respectively, would look like this instead:

```
echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "message"=> "Empty field found."));
...
echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "message"=> "all filled boxes are users"));
...
echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "message"=> $x."is not a user."));
```

On the JavaScript side, you would have:

```
..., function(response) {
    result = JSON.parse(response);
    (result.success) ? ...success code... : alert(result.message);
});
```

Depending on what you want, the object you pass from the PHP can vary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much I will make those changes, haven't even been thinking about security, good to be reminded.